# 1 cakePHP core, multiple applications on different servers

Tags: cakephp

I wondered if this would be possible. I'd like to **centralize my cakePHP core files** at 1 location, and want my several applications to use the same core. One reason is when updating I just need to update one core. Nowadays I always upload the whole cakephp package with each application.

But my applications are not all on the same server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure webservers can access files across physical servers; and even if it could via network shares, this would be an incredible performance hit.

Rather try to automate the core deploy using SVN or RSync tools.

SO, while it may technically be possible, I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 4):

If your apps are at different servers than your cake core, you’ll need at least all servers to be in the same network so you can mount one server’s disk from the other one. Otherwise, you’ll need to upload the core into each app.

Assuming you can mount the disks, you can use the same cake core just replacing the paths in **app/webroot/index.php**

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest to do either, but I would add also that updating core is good, but not always good. Especially if your applications are on a live servers (users are working on them).

I have bad experience in the past while doing such upgrades and there are several places in the application where some parts of the code were deprecated and the application stopped working. (I am speaking for 1.2 to 1.3 migrations), so my philosophy is: if you start with one version of the framework keep it the same, unless there is something critical which upper version will improve or fix.

I am not saying it's bad to upgrade, but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always advise to keep the core up-to-date if possible, but each update needs to be well tested before being deployed. Even 1.3.x point updates can cause things to break in edge cases. As such, I'll keep an app updated if it's still under active development, but not necessarily if it's frozen in production.

Tying several different apps to the same core means you need to test all apps together when upgrading just one core. Work quickly multiplies this way. This is especially annoying if you depend on a bug fix in a newer core release, but this new release introduces some obscure problem in another app.

In the end each app is specifically written for a specific version of the Cake core. In theory the API should not change between point releases and things should just keep humming along when upgrading the core, but in practice that's not always how it works. As such, keep each app bundled with a core that it's tested and proven to work with. The extra hard disk space this requires is really no problem these days.